# asp.net mvc 2 grid helper

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am looking for some source code for a JQgrid html helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may [download it from here](https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/Mvcjqgrid). And here's the [accompanying blog post](http://www.webpirates.nl/webpirates/robin-van-der-knaap/47-fluent-jqgrid-html-helper-for-aspnet-mvc).